# How to add loop counter value as array name suffix

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 variant arrays:
Array1
Array2
Array3

I am wanting to add the counter value of my for loop to the end of the array name to save repeating the same code line over e.g. :

```
For i = 1 To oXlWkBk.Sheets.Count
FillArray ArraySource & i, "B1:" & oCurrentWs.Cells(lNumRows, lNumCols).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Next i
```

instead of:

```
For i = 1 To oXlWkBk.Sheets.Count
FillArray ArraySource1, "B1:" & oCurrentWs.Cells(lNumRows, lNumCols).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

FillArray ArraySource2, "B1:" & oCurrentWs.Cells(lNumRows, lNumCols).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

FillArray ArraySource3, "B1:" & oCurrentWs.Cells(lNumRows, lNumCols).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Next i
```

I've tried using:

- Array & i
- Array & Cstr(i)
- Array(i)

Is it possible to append the counter value as a suffix to complete the array name?

Comment: Nope.  Put them in a `Scripting.Dictionary` instead. Then you can use string keys.

Comment: ...or put your arrays in an array and use the numeric index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dim Arrays As Variant
Arrays = Array(Array1, Array2, Array3)

For i = 1 To oXlWkBk.Sheets.Count
    FillArray Arrays(i-1), "B1:" & oCurrentWs.Cells(lNumRows, lNumCols).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Next i
```

Since `Array()` returns a 0-based array you need to be careful with the indices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I try this I get a compile error: Type Mismatch: Array or user-defined type expected. Not sure why this as I already have the Arrays array declared via `Public Arrays() as Variant`

Comment: @BLothian Drop the `()` and declare it as `Arrays As Variant` rather than `Arrays() As Variant`. You don't need to declare `Arrays` as an array -- just declare it as a simple variant variable. There is a difference between a variant which happens to contain an array and an array of variants. Along the same lines, if there is still a problem you could change the declaration of `FillArray` so that its first argument is a simple variant and not anything more specific, although this is less likely to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to store all three arrays inside an array and then reference the containing array with the `i`? For example,

```
Sub test()
largerArray = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
For i = 0 To 2
    Debug.Print (sumArray(largerArray(i)))
Next i
End Sub
Function sumArray(thisArray As Variant) As Integer
sumArray = 0
For i = LBound(thisArray) To UBound(thisArray)
    sumArray = sumArray + thisArray(i)
Next i
End Function
```

So in your case, you would have

```
largerArray=Array(ArraySource1, ArraySource2, ArraySource3)
for i=0 to oXlWkBk.Sheets.Count
    FillArray largerArray(i), "B1:" & oCurrentWs.Cells(lNumRows, lNumCols).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

etc.
```