# LBound of arrays stored inside variant

Tags: arrays, vba

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901482/how-to-add-loop-counter-value-as-array-name-suffix) I was given an answer which solved my problem but as I have been going through my code I have noticed something odd. When I assign the 3 arrays to the arrays variant, I can see in the locals window that the LBound of the variant starts at 0 (as expected) however the individual arrays LBound starts at 1 even though I have written `Option Base 0` at the top of the module. Is this correct?

Code to populate array

```
Public Sub FillArray(ByRef data As Variant, 
                    sRange As String) 
data = oCurrentWs.Range(sRange) End Sub
```

Comment: Is your fill arrays using for x=1 to y on the range or does it populate using arr=range(x), can you put a touch more code around what you have to?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have:
`Public Sub FillArray(ByRef data As Variant, sRange As String)`
`data = oCurrentWs.Range(sRange)`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because the assignment of a `Range` to a `Variant` would always result in a 1-lowerbounded array, regardless of any `Option Base` setting.

as you can see with this test:

```
    Public Sub FillArray(ByRef data As Variant, sRange As String)
        With oCurrentWs.Range(sRange)
            ReDim data(0 To .Rows.Count - 1, 0 To .Columns.Count - 1) '<--| this dims 'data' as a 0-based array
            data = .Value '<--| this redims 'data' as a 1-based array
        End With
    End Sub
```

so if you *really* need to have 0-based arrays you have to code like follows:

```
Public Sub FillArray(ByRef data As Variant, sRange As String)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With oCurrentWs.Range(sRange)
        ReDim data(0 To .Rows.Count - 1, 0 To .Columns.Count - 1) '<--| dim 'data' as a zero-based array
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count '<--| loop through referenced range rows
            For j = 1 To .Columns.Count '<--| loop through referenced range columns
                data(i - 1, j - 1) = .Cells(i, j) '<--| fill each array element individually
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Only just getting back to this. Thanks for the explanation and sample code. I've tested it and it works great, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Variant arrays are dynamic arrays of the Variant type
these are initialized using "`= Array(`)".

**Advantage**

as they are initialized using "`= Array()`", `LBound` and `UBound` functions work with them even when they have no elements:

```
Dim varr As Variant

  varr = Array()

  Debug.Print LBound(varr) 'Prints 0
  Debug.Print UBound(varr) 'Prints -1
```

Now we can also add an element without checking for UBound failure

**Excel Ranges Use Base 1**

When an array is populated straight from a range the array will start at 1 and not 0.

For more information refer to the [Cells & Ranges > Working With Arrays](http://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm)

Comment: Whilst I appreciate the reply it doesn't relate to the issue I've described as there is no problem with the LBound and UBound of the variant. Refer to the image at the following link which shows the problem: http://i.imgur.com/J7uzspf.png